# From the start of Cheers, does Sam ever drink alcohol?

Tags: character, frasier, cheers

In Cheers, Sam is a recovering alcoholic who doesn't drink. From the first episode onward, does Sam ever drink? For the purpose of this question, I will include answers where he's seen drinking on-screen (obviously), but also other characters referring to Sam's drinking where the drinking occurred during or after the first episode of Cheers. So the period during which he played baseball drunk don't count.

Answers may refer to any episode of Cheers or Frasier (as they're set in the same universe and Sam appears on Frasier at least one time).

I'm asking because Sam is (an integral part of) Cheers (the series) and getting to know Sam is vital to understanding much of his interactions with other people in the series.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93090/discussion-on-question-by-jjj-from-the-start-of-cheers-does-sam-ever-drink-alco).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> From the start of Cheers, does Sam ever drink alcohol?

## Yes

At the end of Season2 / beginning of Season 3

> After the "end" of the on-off relationship between Sam and Diane in the previous season, **Sam begins drinking again** and indulges in a series of affairs;
>
> <sup>[**wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheers_(season_3))</sup>